# JSP No class Found Error org.hibernate.Session on tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, tomcat

I have included all necessary jar filex in my folder but it raises run time error saying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session`. Here is screenshot of my project hierarchy

[image]

One thing if run this by making a main function and run it as java application then it works fine and give correct output but on tomcat as a web application it raise error.

Anyone here please guide me

Comment: where u add the jar files

Comment: Try it including jar libraries in WEB-INF/lib/ directory in order to it will be availables for web deployment.

Comment: I have included all jar files in Java Build Path
How can i add it inside Web-INF Folder?

Comment: Java build path is used for compilation, yourapp.war/WEB-INF/lib is used by application server when it deploys / runs your application. You need to setup your project correctly so dependecies are copied to this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this go to `Properties` of the `Project`,then select the `Deployment Assembly`,then Click on `Add` and select `Java Build Path Entries` and Add your `Hibernate` and then Click on `Finish`.Then check your problem is resolved or not.

Comment: I have included all jar files in Java Build Path

Comment: then once clean the project and then try to build

Comment: Did u follow my answer ?

Comment: **Tomcat** was not able to read your **java build path** of your eclipse.To resolve this Either you need to follow the steps in my answer or you need to copy all jars and paste them in your WEB-INF/lib folder,then only they will placed into your war and deployed into the tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

According to findjar.com, the org.hibernate.Session class can be found in these jar files:

http://www.findjar.com/class/org/hibernate/Session.html;jsessionid=53FA854532D73E1B1CC5E6EF2073A461

Include the hibernate 3 jar in your web-inf folder, as well as your other jars as mentioned by @angel_navarro

Comment: I have included all jar files in Java Build Path
How can i add it inside Web-INF Folder?